# how to call upload.php file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've made a flie upload.php which uploads the .docx file to the server.It is working properly.
Now I want to upload file without refreshing the page using the same php file. How can I call the php file using ajax ??
and how to show the message sent by upload.php ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
</form>

<script>
 $('form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "link/to/the/upload.php" ,
                data: ('form').serialize(),
                success : function(data) {
                    alert('Uploaded!');
                },
                fail: function(data) {
                    alert('failed to upload');
                    }
            });
    });
</script>
```